# How to display images coming from webservice in android

Tags: android

We are working on a project where data is coming from webservice.I am dispalying that data in listview.The data icludes images as image path.I have displayed all the iformation but i couldt display the image.How to display the images from webservices.

my code is:

```
package com.example.doctreachapp;



 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import com.example.doctreachapp.JSONParser;
 import com.example.doctreachapp.R;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class GeneralHospitals extends ListActivity {
private Context context;
private static String url = "my Url";
// private static final String ID = "ID";
String TAG_user_detail = "DentalHospitals";
private static final String Img = "Img";
private static final String Location = "Location";
private static final String URL = "URL";
private static final String Name = "Name";
private static final String Distance = "Distance";

String imagestack;
 Bitmap image; 
JSONArray user_detail_jsonarray = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    new ProgressTask().execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        setListView();
        // select single ListView item
        // lv = getListView();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // get JSON data from URL
        // JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        Log.d("json", json.toString());
        try {
            user_detail_jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("DentalHospitals");
            Log.d("jsonarray", user_detail_jsonarray.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < user_detail_jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject c = user_detail_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String img = c.getString(Img);
                String name = c.getString(Name);
                String loc = c.getString(Location);
                String url = c.getString(URL);
                String dis = c.getString(Distance);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                map.put(Img, img);
                map.put(Name, name);
                map.put(Location, loc);
                map.put(URL, url);
                map.put(Distance, dis);
                jsonlist.add(map);
                // Log.d("list",jsonlist);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("JSONList", jsonlist.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listData;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist) {
        this.listData = jsonlist;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.Location = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.loc);
            holder.URL = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.url);
            holder.Distance = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.dis);
            holder.Img = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
          //System.out.println(listData.get(position).get("Img"));
            System.out.println(listData.get(position).get("Name"));
        holder.Img.setImageURI(listData.get(position).get("Img"));
        holder.Name.setText(listData.get(position).get("Name"));
        holder.Location.setText(listData.get(position).get("Location"));
        holder.URL.setText(listData.get(position).get("URL"));
        holder.Distance.setText(listData.get(position).get("Distance"));
        //WebView image = holder.Img;

        //imagestack = listData.get(position).get("Img");
        //image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((listData.get(position).get("Img")).openStream());
        Log.d("image",imagestack);

        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView Img;
    TextView Location;
    TextView Name;
    TextView URL;
    TextView Distance;
}

public void setListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, jsonlist);
    Log.d("ABCD", "" + lv.getVisibility());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}




    Please help me.
```

Comment: Seriously, just search how to load an Image from URL and set it to an ImageView.

Comment: @shkschneider: i searched but i couldt found...that is why i am posting here

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: If you typed what I wrote "how to load an Image from URL and set it to an ImageView" into google, you'll have found below correct answer as first answer from Google. Learn how to search.

Comment: Use Volley library for WS calls and getting the picture from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in your `getView()` where you have initialized `holder.Img` `ImageView`

```
 new DownloadImageTask(holder.Img)
            .execute(listData.get(position).get("Img"));
```

Below is the `AsyncTask` to download the image and to display it in the `ImageView`

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
          ImageView bmImage;

          public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
              this.bmImage = bmImage;
          }

          @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
              String urldisplay = urls[0];
              Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
              try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return mIcon11;
          }

          protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
              bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

          }
        }
```

If you have small number of items in the `ListView` then use the above code else it recommendable to use [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) .

Comment: i am getting this error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> to 
 ImageView

Comment: On which line you got this error ? I am sure you must have done some simple error.

Comment: holder.Img = new DownloadImageTask(holder.Img)
    .execute(listData.get(position).get("Img"));......in this line

Comment: write only `new DownloadImageTask(holder.Img) .execute(listData.get(position).get("Img"));`